# How to get 3.3 output voltage in PC817 opto coupler?

Tags: opto-isolator, 3.3v

[image]

I am using `PC817` opto coupler.  I want a 3.3 output voltage. In its 1st pin I am giving 12volt and 2nd pin is gnd. I have connected a pull down resistor on 3rd pin. But i am confused because when I am giving 3.3volt on 4th pin, and I am checking output from 3rd pin which is 1.5volt. How can I get 3.0 - 3.3volt output on 3rd pin.

I have tested it with 5 volt, means when I was giving 5 volt on 4th pin and when I was checking voltage on 3rd pin it was 4.7-4.8v which is I think correct. But I dont know what is happening in case of 3.3volt. PLease help.

Thanks

EDIT : i have attached a screenshot of proteus simulation. I actually didnt find the PC817 opto coupler but I got the similar opto coupler. I am getting an output voltage of 3.22. Please tell me that is this connection good. I mean if I make this connection in real, will this work?

Comment: post the schematics. Do you have resistor between 12 V and Pin #1? What is the pull down value? Ideally you should have a pull up resistor. The Opto will drive the transistor output low when the Diode is driven. Pls post all resistor values along with the schematics to give a possibly useful answer.

Comment: I cannot post the schematics but i can tell you the resistor value. I am using 1k res on pin1 and a pull down resistor of 1k on 3rd pin. also from 3rd pin I am using 1k resistor and I am checking the output from this resistor which is 1.5v when I am applying 3.3v on 4th pin. If this is wrong can you suggest me another circuit?

Comment: You certainly can post schematics. If you can't take a screenshot of the relevant bit, use the built in schematic editor to redraw it.

Comment: @annacarolina For your next question, you can also use the Schematic Editor on the forum to supply more information. It's an icon above where you type the text. 7th from left. (Or hotkey Ctrl+M). If you supply a schematic with values as you use it, we will be able to offer much better answers much quicker.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try using the setup as shown in the figure. The 1 K value on pin one is fine, but increase the value of resistor to 100k between Pin 4 and 3.3 V. When there is no 12 V on pin 1, The output (Pin Number 4) will be high, and when there is 12 V on Pin 1, the transistor will turn on shorting the Pin 4 to ground (VCE will be less than 100-200 mV). please try this and reply if not possible.[image]

I am using the same setup, different kind of coupler and it is working.

Comment: you are saying that  when input is low, output will be high and vice versa. But I dont want it like this. I want that when I give 12v supply on pin 1 my output should be 3.0-3.3volt

Comment: I would not opt for that option. i will use a transistor at the input of pin 1 as inverter if in case, the 12 V drive is impossible to invert. I feel that,when the collector (opto coupler)current flows, the drop developed across emitter will be comparable with collector voltage thus limiting the base current (negative feedback). I might be wrong too. )

Comment: i have attached a screenshot of proteus simulation. I actually didnt find the PC817 opto coupler but I got the similar opto coupler. I am getting an output voltage of 2.93. Please tell me that is this connection good. I mean if I make this connection in real, will this work?

Comment: @anna If 3 V is acceptable (normally yes), then i see no issues. where r you connecting the 3 V output?

Comment: I am using PIC32MX795F512L microcontroller, and this controller can work only in case of 3.3v. So i am giving this voltage to controller.Is this thing correct.?

Comment: @anna are you planning to power on MCU with the output of coupler. OR it is only the input?

Comment: @anna MCU can detect the input voltage as high if it is above 80% of VDD (2.64 V). So you can connect it to MCU directly. Refer to TABLE 31-8: DC CHARACTERISTICS: I/O PIN INPUT SPECIFICATIONS in the datasheet

Comment: output of the coupler is used as input to the PIC32MX795F512L. I also want to know one thing that while I was running a led blinking program on pic32 starter kit. I measured the voltage on output pin and that was 3.15 and in my case I am planning to give voltage which is 3.22-3.33. so is it safe to give this much voltage? or it should be below or equal to 3.15. What will happen if I give voltage above 3.3 like 3.5 or 3.7 to the controller as input?

Comment: The input can be same as supply of PIC IC> If you are powering the MCU with 3.3 V, Input shouldn't cross 3.3 V. It is okay to have 3.33 but not above 3.4 V. The IO pins will/may have ESD protection diodes, which start conducting when the input voltage exceeds the VDD, causing significant current flow damaging the IO port /PIC.

Comment: Thanks Umar you are really helpful. thanks for sharing your knowledge. Have you worked on PIC32 ethernet starter kit?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

If you have 12V feeding the input diode via 1K you will be producing a forward current of about 10mA. If you have a 1k resistor on the output that you hope to have 3V3 across it means an output current (Ic) of 3.3mA.

It looks to me like you will probably achieve about 3.2 volts on the output but this is a typical example only. In my experience, a lot of opto devices are worse than this so try driving the input a little harder (maybe 20mA) and try increasing the output resistor from 1k to 10k.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect your PC817 as shown below you should be able to achieve a "non inverting" output.

[image]

Here is an LTSpice simulation waveform that shows the output voltage level that should be achievable.

[image]

Note that the timing delay response through the optocoupler in the PC817A model may not represent an accurate picture of the real delays to be expected in a physical circuit implementation. On the otherhand the voltage and current transfer characteristics are modeled in a reasonable manner.

Comment: i have attached a screenshot of proteus simulation. I actually didnt find the PC817 opto coupler but I got the similar opto coupler. I am getting an output voltage of 2.93. Please tell me that is this connection good. I mean if I make this connection in real, will this work?

Comment: @annacarolina - It should work for you. Remember to keep your load on the output to very small current. Two things can be adjusted - increase current through input diode by reducing the value of the R1 in my diagram - or increase the value of the R2 in my diagram.

Answer (score -2):

```
Use LM7805 to convert 12V into  5V
```

[image]

```
Then use this voltage divider to create 3.3V supply
```

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff9ioE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Use the circuit below , and as  datasheet suggests that the forward voltage is about 1.2V (led voltage) and maximum current should be 20mA so the resistor R1 can be calculated as

```
Voltage_R1 = 5.0-1.2  = 3.8V
I_R1 = 20mA 
R1 = 3.8 / 20mA = 190 ohm
```

Use minimum resistor of value this , higher resistor will reduce current

[image]

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49141/did-i-use-this-optocoupler-correctly

Comment: you are giving 3.3v input. but in my circuit i'll have to give 12volt supply and output should be 3.3v. How to do that?

Comment: Bring 12 V to 3.3 or 4 using voltage divider

Comment: This isn't a "3.3v source", it's a voltage divider, and along with wasting 20mA constantly, it will also have extremely poor output regulation.

Comment: use 7805 at 12V convert to 5 then use voltage divider

Comment: Why would you convert to 5V, when you want 3.3v?

Comment: I am still getting 1.5 v on output. I am really confused how to get this output. pls help

Comment: Try to give 5V on the instead of 3.3  and tell me the output.

Comment: If i am giving 5v then i am getting 4.86v

Comment: @TaimoorAli I downvoted it because it's _wrong_.

Comment: @nickJohnson can you tell me why is it wrong

Comment: I've already said - because you're trying to use a voltage divider as a regulated power supply.

Comment: @annacarolina http://www.mkpochtoi.ru/pc817_ds.pdf

Comment: but the supply to that voltage divider is being regulated by lm7805 , what problem would it do

Comment: you are usng breadboard right , post its picture or the schematic you are using

Comment: I am using PC817 which has 1,2,3,4 pins. I am giving 12v to 1 pin and want 3.3 as output

Comment: @TaimoorAli i have attached a screenshot of proteus simulation. I actually didnt find the PC817 opto coupler but I got the similar opto coupler. I am getting an output voltage of 2.93. Please tell me that is this connection good. I mean if I make this connection in real, will this work?

Comment: @annacarolina yes it will work , because in this situation 10.6mA will pass through led which is below the maximum required current and  the switching process will be sufficient for your application

Comment: @annacarolina didnt it work ?

Comment: yes it is working and giving me output of 3.2-3.3 v but I still have to test it with PIC32MX795F512L